# Mysql and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, service-pack

I today install SP1 on my Windows Server 2008 R2, but after the mandatory reboot are the MySQL server unable to start, where i get the following error.

```
C:\Users\Cronjob>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults
-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini"
110411 17:51:28 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be re
moved in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.
110411 17:51:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110411 17:51:28  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I have tryed to remove the "read only" on the data dir "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data" but this dose not help.

Any idears to how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the file permissions got dropped by the service pack.

1. Find which account is running the MySQL service by checking the "account" field in `services.msc`.
2. Grant that account read/execute/modify permissions on the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL` directory.
3. Make sure those rights inherit down to the files in the data directory.